# Duplicate detection and reporting in a BST

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-search

For the purpose of this problem, the BST is defined to allow duplicates, and the duplicate values will always follow to the right-side of the parent nodes with the same value. For example, with the data:

```
 1, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

if the root node has the value 2 (as opposed to 1) then the tree will look like:

```
          2
         / \
        1   2
             \
              2
               \
                2
```

The following code scans the tree, identifies any values that are duplicated, and prints the duplicate values, as well as how many times that value is duplicated.

```
public class DuplicateCountInBST {

    private TreeNode root;

    private class TreeNode {
        TreeNode left;
        int item;
        TreeNode right;

        TreeNode (TreeNode left, int item, TreeNode right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.item = item;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }

    private class DuplicateInfo {
        int item; 
        int count;

        public DuplicateInfo(int item, int count) {
            this.item = item;
            this.count = count;
        }
    }

    public void print () {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
        // find right most node.
        TreeNode rightMostNode = root;
        while (rightMostNode.right != null) {
            rightMostNode = rightMostNode.right;
        }

        printHelper (root, root.item, new DuplicateInfo(0, 0), rightMostNode);
    }

    // inorder traversal
    // rightmostnode is a guard against skewed trees.
     private void printHelper (TreeNode node, int prevValue, DuplicateInfo duplicateInfo, TreeNode rightMostNode) {
         if (node == null) {
             return;
         }

         printHelper(node.left, node.item, duplicateInfo, rightMostNode);

         if (node.item == duplicateInfo.item) {
             duplicateInfo.item = node.item;
             duplicateInfo.count++;

         } 
         if (node.item != duplicateInfo.item || node == rightMostNode) {
             if (duplicateInfo.count > 1) {
                 System.out.println(duplicateInfo.item + " : " + duplicateInfo.count);
             }
             duplicateInfo.item = node.item;
             duplicateInfo.count = 1;
         }


         printHelper(node.right, node.item, duplicateInfo, rightMostNode);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### General

Your code style here is good, the variable names are nice and descriptive, and the algorithm you implement is easy to identify and follow. This is good-looking code. There are a few of nit-picks:

- the `TreeNode` class should be a 'static' class ... `private static ...` because it has no reason to keep a reference to the outer class.
- Your `TreeNode.item` should be `final` even though it is an internal class. `final` variables make for more apparent logic.
- this is an opinion thing, but I prefer there to be getter/setter methods *even on internal classes*. With modern IDE's like Eclipse, IntelliJ and NetBeans, there really is no 'lazy' excuse for it. I prefer methods like `node.getRight()` instead of `node.right`
- your method `print()` should have a better name like `printDuplicates()`

### Algorithm

The solution you have for this problem appears to work. The algorithm relies on passing a token around, and relies on first walking the right-edge of the tree to create a 'stop-gate'. These two items detract from the solution. There are 'simpler' ways to do this recursive problem without the overheads you have. Consider the functions:

```
public void printDuplicates() {
    printDuplicatesHelper(root, 0, 0);
}

private void printDuplicatesHelper(final TreeNode node, final int parentval, final int parentcount) {
    if ((node == null || node.item != parentval) && parentcount > 1) {
        System.out.printf("Item %d was duplicated %d times\n", parentval, parentcount);
    }
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    // make sure the parentcount is 0 going left.
    printDuplicatesHelper(node.left, 0, 0);
    printDuplicatesHelper(node.right, node.item, node.item == parentval ? (parentcount + 1) : 1);
}
```

The above functions also do an in-order scan of the data. The difference is that the recursion is designed to go *past* the leaf node, and to treat the `null` node as if it was the end of a duplicate streak. By doing it this way, and by pushing the duplicate-detecting values down with the recursion, you can detect the end-of-duplicates in a much easier pattern.

I created a 'main method' that compares the above code with yours:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     TreeNode left = new TreeNode(null, 1, new TreeNode(null, 1, null));
     TreeNode right = new TreeNode(
              new TreeNode(null, 5, new TreeNode(null, 5, null)), 6, new TreeNode(null, 6, new TreeNode(null, 6, null)));
    TreeNode top = new TreeNode(left, 3, right);

    DuplicateCountInBST tree = new DuplicateCountInBST();
    tree.root = top;
    tree.print();
    tree.printDuplicates();
}
```

And the results I get from running the two calls are:

> ```
> 1 : 2
> 5 : 2
> 6 : 3
> Item 1 was duplicated 2 times
> Item 5 was duplicated 2 times
> Item 6 was duplicated 3 times
> ```